# Chrome: command-line switch is stuck in profiles! How to fix?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

On one computer, I had the command line switch `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` on the icon that starts Chrome.

Later, I created additional profiles.

Now, I've removed that command line switch from the icon. However, each of the profiles still has that switch in effect. When viewing `chrome://version/`, I see:

[image]

How do I remove that from each of the profiles?

I've looked through `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` where I see folders "Profile 1", "Profile 2", etc. but have not found anything useful.

**More Info based on comments**

Here are the properties of the Chrome icon, the only one I have. There is nothing after what you see in the Target field. Until a couple of days ago, I did have the command line switch there.

[image]

Also, when starting Chrome, it first asks for which profile I am using. All those profiles seem to have the switch embedded in them.

Comment: That's an odd one you've got there. So you have one profile now with the switch removed, but others where it remains?

Comment: False alarm.  I must not have closed all instances of Chrome, so the change had not taken effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you've removed the switches from your shortcut properly.

Take a look here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/#windows

> Windows:
>
> 1. Exit any running-instance of Chrome.
> 2. Right click on your "Chrome"
>    shortcut.
> 3. Choose properties.
> 4. At the end of your "Target:" line add
>    the command-line switch. For example:
>    `--disable-gpu-vsync`
> 5. With that example flag, it should look like below (replacing "--disable-gpu-vsync" with any other command-line
>    switch you want to use): chrome.exe --disable-gpu-vsync
> 6. Launch
>    Chrome like normal with the shortcut.

Comment: I suspect that I had not fully closed all instances of Chrome.  When I did, the issue was gone.  So it seems that the profiles do not keep their own settings.